# Python shorthand conditional

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

Here's a quick one...

In Python one can do:

```
foo = foo1 if bar1 else foo2
```

And that's cool, but how can I just get a True or False without having to write

```
foo = True if bar1 else False
```

For example, in JS you can forcibly cast a boolean type by doing

```
var foo = !!bar1;
```

Comment: May I ask why you need this? I hope you're not planning to write something like `if condition == True:`...

Comment: It's because I'm lazy and need to assign a boolean variable depending on a conditional statement, so this way is faster to write

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Call `bool` on the object:

```
bool(bar1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to JavaScript, you can use logical negation in Python. This uses the keyword `not`. One disadvantage of `bool` is you can change its value, as this is not a reserved word. If `bool` variable's value is not callable. For example, `bool = 7`, an error will be raised. If `bool` variable's value is callable. For example, `bool = int`, you may get an unexpected value.

**JavaScript**

```js
!!bar1
```

**Python**

```py
not not bar1
```